# Заменить буквы слова на зеркальные

Tags: php

Например дано слово `apple`. Нужно заменить буквы данного слова на зеркальные:

```
a->z
p->k
p->k
l->o
e->v
```

На выходе должно получиться слово `zkkov`

Мой код:

```php
<?php
$original = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
$replace = array_reverse($original);

$user_input = ['Apple'];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($user_input); $i++) {
    $user_input_new = str_ireplace($original, $replace, $user_input);    
}
var_dump($user_input_new);
```

Вывод:

```php
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "akkle"
}
```

Comment: вроде норм. в чем, собственно, вопрос?

Comment: @Yakoffka вместо 'zkkov' выводит 'akkle', не все буквы переворачивает

Comment: не работает, потому что функция замены заменяет эти символы циклом. на первой итерации `a` на `z`, а когда доходит до конца алфавита, то возвращает назад `z` на `a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$original =['1'=>'a', '2'=>'b', '3'=>'c', '4'=>'d', '5'=>'e', '6'=>'f', '7'=>'g', '8'=>'h', '9'=>'i', '10'=>'j', '11'=>'k', '12'=>'l', '13'=>'m', '14'=>'n', '15'=>'o', '16'=>'p', '17'=>'q', '18'=>'r', '19'=>'s', '20'=>'t', '21'=>'u', '22'=>'v', '23'=>'w', '24'=>'x', '25'=>'y', '26'=>'z'];

$str='apple';
$array = str_split($str);
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

    foreach ($original as $key1 => $value1) {

        if($value==$value1){
            $at[]=$original[abs($key1-'27')];
        }
    }
}

$com = implode("", $at);
print_r($com);
```

Comment: а не проще было сделать `$map = array_combine(array_reverse($original), $original)` и обойтись без вложенных циклов и всяких там `abs, 27` ?

Comment: сделай своим ответом )

Comment: Что за дичь, strtr уже давно существует.

Comment: Что за дичь где ++

Answer (score 0):

// второй вариант, на основе комментариев (как указать лимит замен для str_ireplace() я так и не нашел)

```
<?php
    $search = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
    $user_input = 'Aa Bb Cc Dd Ee Ff Gg Hh Ii Jj Kk Ll Mm Nn Oo Pp Qq Rr Ss Tt Uu Vv Xx Yy Zz';

    $trans = array_combine($search, array_reverse($search));
    $res = strtr(strtolower($user_input), $trans);

    echo $res; // zz yy xx ww vv uu tt ss rr qq pp oo nn mm ll kk jj ii hh gg ff ee cc bb aa
```

Comment: а может стоит почитать документацию к тем методам, которые вы используете? и не только первый абзац, а целиком

Comment: читал, и, тем не менее, нахожу поведение str_ireplace() слегка нелогичным.

Answer (score 0):

Самый красивый вариант из выше представленных:

```
$original = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
$replace = array_reverse($original);


echo strtr('apple', array_combine($original, $replace));
```

Comment: Тот -же самый вариант, что и у @Yakoffka.